# Prevent file which was removed earlier in git history from being removed when pulling branch into site

Tags: git

I am working on a Drupal project which requires the database configuration to be set in a file called `settings.php`.  Because this file varies locally it is not normally stored in git.  Unfortunately, a colleague added it to the repository.  The file has since been removed from the repo and the file added to gitignore. These changes have been committed and already pushed to origin.  A number of other commits have also been made since then, so in other words, the commit which removes the file from the repo is not the most recent commit.

I am trying to deploy the latest repo changes to the webserver. When I try to pull latest commits into the server I get an permissions error, as the `settings.php` on the server is not writable.  I guess what's happening is that git is trying to playing back the commits on pull and is probably trying to remove the `settings.php` file, which is not possible given the file is read only. At least that is what I assume is going on.

Is there anyway that I can pull in the latest commits without git trying to remove the existing `settings.php` file?

I have read about `git rm --cached <file>` and `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` commands.  But am not clear if these will work given that the commit which removed the `settings.php` file is not the most recent commit.

Comment: How many people work with this repo? If it's not too many, then rebase (see answers) is a clear best solution.

Comment: Only two people using the repo

Answer (score 1):

The `--cached` options that you are trying only affect the working tree/index. In other words, they will have no effect when you haven't just deleted the file yourself without committing it. So the fact that a commit exists at all means that these operations won't do what you want them to do.

There are two options at this point:

1. Use an 'interactive rebase' to go back to the commit that did remove the `settings.php` file, restore the file, and then commit amend/rewrite the history. This will be invasive and will potentially require all other people working on the project (and the server) to do a rebase to bring them back into line. This will result in the cleanest history but be aware that it will take some effort to achieve.
2. Copy the last-known-good version from a previous commit, and then commit that anew into the repository. It will mean there are some commits in the history that are broken but requires the smallest amount of work to restore and won't negatively affect other developers or the server.

(You can in fact go from 2 to 1 by doing an interactive rebase subsequently if that's what you want.)

You can find out what the commit was by doing:

```
git log --summary -- settings.php
```

This will show all commits where `settings.php` (assuming it's in the root of the repository) were changed. If it's lower down, use `path/to/settings.php` (where `path` is at the top level of the git repository).

Once you've found the commit where it was deleted, you can do:

```
git show HASH~:settings.php
```

This gets the commit's parent (*HASH~*) and then shows the contents of the file from a given path (`settings.php`). You'll need to use the full path from the root of the repo if necessary (`git show HASH~:path/to/settings.php`).

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply.  In option 2 you mention the need to copy the last-known-good version from a previous commit and then commit anew into the repository.  Because the settings.php should not have been added to GIt in the first place, the last-known-good version is the commit before the settings.php file was added. So can I just checkout that commit and then recommit it to head of the branch.  Then do I just recommit all the other commits following that last-known-good one, with the exception of the commit where settings.php was removed?

Comment: If the last known version was of `settings.php` not existing, then a simple commit deleting `settings.php` should fix it for you, surely?

Comment: A commit has already been made which removes the settings.php file.  This issue is that because it was added and then removed in separate commits, when the branch changes are pulled on another machine, it will try to remove the settings.php on that machine as it plays back the commits.  I don't want it to do this.  I just want to be able to pull the changes to the branch and not have GIT touch the existing settings.php file.